# Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' only in live server

Tags: magento2.2.9

I have developed a Magento site on localhost. Than I uploaded it to live server, there I got some functionality problems. Whenever I run forgot password page and click submit I got this error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Validate_Exception): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress'

Exception #0 (Zend_Validate_Exception): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress'
<pre>#1 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:107]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#3 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#4 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#5 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'customer_account', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'), array('customer_account'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/ForgotPasswordPost/Interceptor.php:26]
#6 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:55]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#10 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000003ab934cd00000000635cecbd#, &Closure#000000003ab934d200000000635cecbd#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#12 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000003ab934cd00000000635cecbd#, &Closure#000000003ab934d200000000635cecbd#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003ab9358500000000635cecbd#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000003ab9356100000000635cecbd#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Similarly if I try to switch between store views on live server I got this error there too, but somehow this is disappeared from store switching now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by itself later on.

Comment: How could you solve the error?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you guide please how it is solved?

Comment: i think you should run "composer update" command. In my case this worked after running other Magento commands like.
php bin/magento setup:update
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 1):

Verify PHP include_path setting. If you use plesk set it to . from PHP setting panel
[image]